# Why did we declare this method synchronized?

Tags: java, concurrency

Consider this class:

```java
// Synchronizing access to shared mutable data using Object 
// methods wait and notifyAll.
public class SynchronizedBuffer implements Buffer
{
    private int buffer = -1; // shared by producer and consumer threads
    private boolean occupied = false;

    // place value into buffer
    public synchronized void blockingPut(int value) throws InterruptedException
    {
        // while there are no empty locations, place thread in waiting state
        while (occupied) 
        {
            // output thread information and buffer information, then wait
            System.out.println("Producer tries to write."); // for demo only
            displayState("Buffer full. Producer waits."); // for demo only
            wait();
        }

        buffer = value; // set new buffer value

        // indicate producer cannot store another value
        // until consumer retrieves current buffer value
        occupied = true;

        displayState("Producer writes " + buffer); // for demo only

        notifyAll(); // tell waiting thread(s) to enter runnable state
    } // end method blockingPut; releases lock on SynchronizedBuffer 

    // return value from buffer
    public synchronized int blockingGet() throws InterruptedException
    {
        // while no data to read, place thread in waiting state
        while (!occupied)
        {
            // output thread information and buffer information, then wait
            System.out.println("Consumer tries to read."); // for demo only
            displayState("Buffer empty. Consumer waits."); // for demo only
            wait();
        }

        // indicate that producer can store another value 
        // because consumer just retrieved buffer value
        occupied = false;

        displayState("Consumer reads " + buffer); // for demo only

        notifyAll(); // tell waiting thread(s) to enter runnable state

        return buffer;
    } // end method blockingGet; releases lock on SynchronizedBuffer 

    // display current operation and buffer state; for demo only
    private synchronized void displayState(String operation)
    {
        System.out.printf("%-40s%d\t\t%b%n%n", operation, buffer, occupied);
    } 
} // end class SynchronizedBuffer
```

And this paragraph from the book:

> ***Notice that method displayState is a synchronized method. This is important because it, too, reads the SynchronizedBuffer’s shared mutable data. Though only one thread at a time may acquire a given object’s lock, one thread may acquire the same object’s lock multiple times—this is known as a reentrant lock and enables one synchronized method to invoke another on the same object.***

Why did we declare method the `displayState()` as synchronized although it's called only from a synchronized method and thus when it's called the calling thread already has the monitor lock on the object?

Comment: Probably as an attempt to demonstrate that you can do that (although it's indeed unnecessary here). If the method was public, or if it was called by another unsynchronized method, making it synchronized would be necessary.

Comment: @StephenC i don't think this is a mistake done by the authors and the evidence is that they assigned a separate paragraph to talk about this method but i didn't understand it and that's why i asked the question

Comment: @user9398992 Could be defensive programming. Although the private method is only called from synchronized method *today*, doesn't mean that some (other) programmer wouldn't try calling it from another un-synchronized method at some future point. Since calling synchronized method from already-synchronized method is cheap, it doesn't hurt, and the guards against accidental misuse in the future.

Comment: Well, I think it is a mistake.  But I think that the mistake was that the author(s) picked a poor example to illustrate that point.

Comment: @Andreas - Possibly.  But since this comes from a book, they would / should have explained that.   This is clearly not real-world code ...

Comment: Yeah, but in real world code, you always synchronize that function because if it touches the objects you want only one thread touching you synchronize every part where it does that as the lock is free but the bugs are basically impossible to figure out.

Comment: ok now there are too many opinions and i didn't get it.. Correct me if i were wrong: when a synchronized method of an object's class is callef from within a thread, and this method calls another method, then it's the same if this other method is synchronized or not, true?

Comment: Besides the unnecessary synchronization, it’s used inconsistently. Despite always printing the actual value of `buffer`, two of the four callers redundantly append the current value of `buffer` to the `operation` argument string before calling the method…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right in questioning this source code. When a method owns the object’s monitor, entering a `synchronized` method or block acquiring the same monitor again, has no effect at all.

It’s also unlikely that the author considered the possibility that future changes to the code could invoke the method without owning the object’s monitor. First of all, the method’s entire purpose is to report the ongoing operation, second, enforcing correct usage could be achieve even simpler.

It’s also interesting that the method is used inconsistently. The method does always report the current value of `buffer`, but two of the four callers redundantly append the current value of `buffer` to the operation argument string before calling the method. Then, there are additional explicit print statements before the two of the callers. Since their message is “[Producer|Consumer] **tries** to [write|read]”, these statements are very likely supposed to report the attempt *before* the loop, instead of inside, at a place where it is already known that the attempt failed.

```
public class SynchronizedBuffer //implements Buffer
{
    private int buffer = -1; // shared by producer and consumer threads
    private boolean occupied = false;

    // place value into buffer
    public synchronized void blockingPut(int value) 
       throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Producer tries to write."); // for demo only
        // while there are no empty locations, place thread in waiting state
        while(occupied) 
        {
           // output thread information and buffer information, then wait
           displayState("Buffer full. Producer waits.", buffer, occupied);// demo only
           wait();
        }

        buffer = value; // set new buffer value

        // indicate producer cannot store another value
        // until consumer retrieves current buffer value
        occupied = true;

        displayState("Producer writes ", buffer, occupied); // for demo only

        notifyAll(); // tell waiting thread(s) to enter runnable state
    } // end method blockingPut; releases lock on SynchronizedBuffer 

    // return value from buffer
    public synchronized int blockingGet() throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Consumer tries to read."); // for demo only
        // while no data to read, place thread in waiting state
        while(!occupied)
        {
            // output thread information and buffer information, then wait
            displayState("Buffer empty. Consumer waits.", buffer, occupied);// demo only
            wait();
        }

        // indicate that producer can store another value 
        // because consumer just retrieved buffer value
        occupied = false;

        displayState("Consumer reads ", buffer, occupied); // for demo only

        notifyAll(); // tell waiting thread(s) to enter runnable state

        return buffer;
    } // end method blockingGet; releases lock on SynchronizedBuffer 

    // display current operation and buffer state; for demo only
    // not accessing the object, hence no synchronization needed
    private static void displayState(String operation, int buffer, boolean occupied)
    {
       System.out.printf("%-40s%d\t\t%b%n%n", operation, buffer, occupied);
    } 
}
```

By turning the state to be reported into parameters, the responsibility to access them in a thread safe manner clearly lies at the caller and by making the method `static`, it’s impossible for the method to incorrectly access object state. Also, redundant reporting of a variable’s value would become apparent at the call site.